# How do I suppress the ODBC dialog box on a DSN-Less connection?

Tags: ms-access, connection, odbc

I am trying to access a MySQL table via a DSNless ODBC connection from Microsoft Access. I ave no problem actually connecting is a valid user name and password is provided. However in either of these are not valid, the ODBC dialog screen appears asking for connection details.  Is there any way of stopping the ODBC dialog screen from appearing and just letting the connection error?

My ODBC connection string is

"ODBC;Driver=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;SERVER=XXXX;DATABASE=XXXX;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;Option=3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at - [19.1.4.2. Connector/ODBC Connection Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html)

Specifically, the "options" parameter and its flag "FLAG_NO_PROMPT"...

Comment: I tried setting OPTION=FLAG_NO_PROMPT but it made no difference. On checking the MySQL website I discovered that their is a known bug which states that this parameter does not work. However on further investigation I found that **FLAG_NO_PROMPT = 16**. Therefore I tried **OPTION=16** and it work. _Many thanks for the help_

Answer (score 1):

This FLAG_NO_PROMPT idea actually works. In the connection string you usually have something like "ODBC;DRIVER=.......; OPTION=3"

Just add 16 for FLAG_NO_PROMPT, i.e. use OPTION=19, and it will suppress the system prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to stop it with a "DoCmd.SetWarnings False".

Another option is to try "On Error Resume Next" at the beginning of the procedure. You could do a check in the code for the "ODBC call failed" error (I think err.number = 3151). Just put an if right after you try to connect to the ODBC, if it fails, send it to an exit.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim db As DAO.Database 'Will also work with ADO
Dim ODBCstr As String

Set db = 'Connect with ODBC here

If Err.Number = 3151 Then 'Could also try If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   GoTo Exit_ThisCode
End If
```

That may work, as long as an error is actually being thrown when it fails to connect. If you choose to check with a specific error code, just make sure you know the right one.

Comment: Public Function MySQLLinkSingle(stTableName As String)
    On Error GoTo SingleLinkTable_Err
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim stConnect As String
     'First unlink the table if it is already linked
    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If td.Name = stTableName Then
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stTableName
        End If
    Next
    'Connect ot external datasource

Comment: stConnect = "ODBC;Driver=" & cODBCdriver & ";SERVER=" & pServer & ";DATABASE=" & cDatabase & ";UID=" & pUsername & ";PWD=" & pPassword & ";Option=3"
    'Link to specified table
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stTableName, stConnect)
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    'Return true if successful
    MySQLLinkSingle = True
    Exit Function

SingleLinkTable_Err:
    'Return false if unsuccessful and display error message
    MySQLLinkSingle = False
End Function

Comment: Problem is it the call to the ODBC driver which is producing the ODBC dialog connection box if one of the parammeters is invalid. This is before it returns to the code with any error.

Comment: Well, the way I fixed a similar problem in the past was just hard-coding in authentication info that our admin setup for my application. I used table driven security and only the people with proper access levels were able to actually get to the screens that required that specific connection.

Comment: I don't think either of these suggestions will actually work, but I would recommend against them, anyway. It's just bad coding practice to depend on either of these (`DoCmd.SetWarnings False` or `On Error Resume Next`) for getting around a real error message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you but the actual argument to the ODBC API SQLDriverConnect which stops dialogue boxes being displayed is SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT. However, you should be warned that not all drivers follow the specification exactly. I don't know how you get MS Access to call SQLDriverConnect with SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is going the DSN route, there is a checkbox under Details that sets the same option:
"Don't prompt when connecting"

[image]